# Arquillian Embedded Derby database columnDefinition="text"

Tags: hibernate, junit, ejb, derby, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian/Embedded derby database to test my EJB`s and i'm dealing with a problem.

I have a field on my class annotated with:

```
@Column(name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition="text")
```

Hibernate tries to create the table with field:

```
CONTENT text
```

and then it gives this error and table is not created:

```
2015-06-09 11:25:56 ERROR SchemaExport:425 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table etc...
2015-06-09 11:25:56 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - TYPE 'TEXT' does not exist.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you verified you're using the correct Hibernate "dialect" for Derby?